# How do I get w3wp.exe process available in the 'Attach to Process' dialogue in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

I have a big asp.net project, I want to attach the process to chrome.

Before, all I did was attach to w3wp.exe process and then run the URL in chrome.

But now, w3wp.exe process is not showing in the 'Attach to Process' dialogue.

**How do I show w3wp.exe in the 'Attach to Process' dialogue?**

Comment: Try clicking the refresh (all processes) button if it's in the 2010 version?

Comment: @IrishChieftain - It didn't appear

Comment: Did you ensure the "show processes from all users/sessions" is selected?

Comment: Spin up the browser on localhost and look for the process again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit the URL first so as thread get active
2. Open attach process dialog
3. Press refresh (if didn't listed)
4. Check Show processes from all users/sessions (if didn't listed)

Comment: All I did was hit the URL in chrome first and wala! it appeared!

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend adding a plugin to make it even easier, such as the 
[AttachTo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0265ab0-df51-4100-8e10-1f84403c4cd0).  With the plugin you can attach in one click without having to navigate the process dialog.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, even if it might be good advice. You should post this as a comment.